# Decrypt fails if content is only a zero (0) with openssl encrypt decrypt

Tags: php, openssl

I am using the following function for encrypt and decrypt of wordpress post content in a WordPress plugin:

```
public static function afz_encrypt_decrypt( $action, $string ) {
    $output = false;

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key     = '12345678901234567890123456789012';
    $iv_size        = 16;

    if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
        $encrypt_iv = mcrypt_create_iv( $iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM );
        $output     = openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $secret_key, 0, $encrypt_iv );
        $output     = base64_encode( $encrypt_iv . $output );
    } else if ( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
        $decrypt_iv = substr( base64_decode( $string ), 0, $iv_size );
        $output     = stripslashes( openssl_decrypt( substr( base64_decode( $string ), $iv_size ), $encrypt_method,
            $secret_key,
            0,
            $decrypt_iv ) );
        if ( false == $output ) {
            $output = $string;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

The above code fails to decrypt the text if the content is ONLY a zero character!!!

It returns the encoded string that encrypt produced.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( false == $output ) {
    $output = $string;
}
```

This checks if the output is "falsy" and if it is it sets `$output` back to the original encrypted string. `"0"` is falsy. Replace the check with

```
if ( false === $output ) {
```

To check if the output is actually false and not just falsy.

For a better explanation of what is and isn't falsy, see [this documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).